# Is there performance benefit to configure recative simple Spring application with kafka producer?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have to create a very simple Spring application that will receive http request and send kafka message. Like that:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send")
public void sendMessage(@RequesyBody body) {
    kafkaTemplate.send((value = "/send"))
}
```

But what about performance here? In case when I resend data to another http service I can configure reactive approach and save threading count. But what I am getting here? Thread per request? Does kafka client has it is own http client under the hood? Or If it uses low level socker connection - can it be configured with event looping?

Btw, as I know 9may be wrong) that reactive style is usefull for requests with small data sending. With kafka I will definitelly sending data continuously. From other point there will be a lot of incoming http requests - so probably it is better to accumulate messages somewhere - do spring kafkaClient do this by default?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is a TCP protocol. There's no HTTP happening here other than the Spring POST mapping .

The code you've shown is not a blocking call, so there's only a slight performance overhead on the TCP connection to the broker, and the in memory buffer that you're actually sending to here. So, yes, Kafka automatically batches data client side. See producer config `batch.size`